# Replicating a postgresql database when master is running on ARM and replication server is x86

Tags: postgresql, cpu-architecture

I have been trying to set up a replicate a master server is running on a raspberry pi to a computer (x86).

I followed an excellent guide:
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-for-postgresql-96-on-ubuntu-1604/

However, trying to start my slave (on the x86 machine), I get the following error in my log

```
2019-12-10 10:40:52.865 CET [19752] FATAL:  database files are incompatible with server
2019-12-10 10:40:52.865 CET [19752] DETAIL:  The database cluster was initialized without USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL but the server was compiled with USE_FLOAT8_BYVAL.
2019-12-10 10:40:52.865 CET [19752] HINT:  It looks like you need to recompile or initdb.
2019-12-10 10:40:52.865 CET [19752] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I was able to find some information stating that replication from ARM to x86 is not possible. But I was hoping someone has an idea how it can be solved.

Comment: Streaming replication only works between the same operating systems and architectures. Your only option is [logical replication](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was worried there would be no options available. Logical replication will certainly do the trick for me. Thanks!